# How to replace elements of unknown content and length in strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I need help with replacing segments of a string in Java.

I have tried both the String method 'replace' and StringTokenizer. As the segments of my strings is of unknown length I guess StringTokenizer is out of question. I also need to go through several strings (with many similar segments to replace in each string). I have assumed there is a command for finding substrings something like "begin with..., and end with..." but have not found any.

As I am new to programming, this case might be simple for all but me...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an example?  What does the strings look like?

Comment: Typically a hierarchical "tree" like below
(Aaa:11.111,(Bbbb:2.222,Cc:3.33)666:4.44)777.77:5;
Where I for ex want to replace everything between ')' and ':' with one the same thing, for ex 'n'.

Comment: Click edit to make any changes in the question as the comment doesn't support any formatting and try to accept correct answers by clicking "Tick mark" to the left of answer.

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't find any methods to find [substrings](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) or Strings that [begin with](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) or [end with](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) certain Strings?  Where did you look?

Answer (score 3):

There are various replace methods in the [String](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class:

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8811/picture2pg.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8811/picture2pg.png)

But it might be really inefficient if you are doing a lot of replaces, as each time a new string is constructed. Instead the [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class works perfectly for that case:

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1667/picture1knk.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1667/picture1knk.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try `string.replaceAll` or `string.replaceFirst`, which allow you to carry out the replacement based on a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

[String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Regex can be just about everything.